# discord.js muted command - reason fucntion

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The Code Works, just not the reason

```
const reason = args[2] || args.slice(1, args.length - 2).join(" ");
```

this will only display the last two words of the reason, I dont know why?
how do I turn it to include the entire reason

(command is `!mute @member [time] [reason])

Answer (score 1):

```
const time = args[1]
const reason = args.slice(2).join(" ");
```